# Remove repeated items in excel columns

Tags: shell, awk

I have an excel file with about 100 columns containing thousands of items, I want to remove repeated items in each column and keep all unique items. I think 'awk' command can help but not sure how to loop it through all columns. my data looks like below

```
     A                 B               C              D
```

BGIBMGA000028   BGIBMGA000016   BGIBMGA000016   BGIBMGA000029
BGIBMGA000029   BGIBMGA000016   BGIBMGA000028   BGIBMGA000029
BGIBMGA000029   BGIBMGA000029   BGIBMGA000029   BGIBMGA000029
BGIBMGA000029   BGIBMGA000029   BGIBMGA000029   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000029   BGIBMGA000029   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000032   BGIBMGA000029   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000064   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000064   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000064   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000064   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000066   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000086   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000086   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000097   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034
BGIBMGA000097   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034   BGIBMGA000034

for example there are four BGIBMGA000034 in column A, the program should remove others and leave only one of it. just unique items in each cell. I was able to write an awk command which can remove duplicates in one column, but I want to loop the same command so it can go through all columns and remove all duplicates... command below

```
$awk '!x[$1]++' file
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. FYI, SO does not provide code writing service. So, show us what have you tried so far, what is issue/s, so that we can help.

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Is there some reason we need to try to spot the duplicates in 15 lines of strings that are 13 characters long? Couldn't you demonstrate your problem in, say, 5 lines of strings that are 2 characters long and maybe even make only the dup ones all upper case so they stand out? Fix the input to be easier for us to read so more people will be willing to do that and try to help you and then add the expected output. And get rid of column "E", it's doing nothing but obfuscate your example.

Comment: "for example there are four BGIBMGA000034 in column A".  I can only see two!

Comment: Ok, guys, I think i formulated the question poorly. the point i want to make is, $awk '!x[$1]++' file worked well in removing duplicates of an item which appeard more than once in an excel column. But the code works for one column at a time. the problem is that I need to get it to loop through every column in the file and remover all duplicates. the looping part is where my problem is. I am new in bash scripting, i know that with time i will get better. please any help

Comment: Why did you in [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34289681/revisions) change the fixed formatting with four columns back so that five columns are formed at the normal screen width? In neither case are there _four BGIBMGA000034 in column A_. How many columns and lines do you intend to present?

Answer (score 1):

(1) You say the data is in CSV format but I don't see any commas, so it's not clear what format
the data is actually in.  From your example, it looks like the columns are whitespace-separated,
so I'm going to use awk in most of what follows, but you might need to use the -F option of awk; or perhaps you could use `cut` or some other tool.

(2) The unique items in column 1 can easily be obtained by

```
 awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

And similarly for the other columns.

(3) If the goal is to take your 4-column input and produce 4-column output, with the assumption that the columns in (2) above can simply be pasted together, then you could write the following, assuming that $IN refers to the input file:

```
#!/bin/bash

IN="$1"

function u { awk -v n="$1" '{print $n}' | sort -u ; }

paste <(u 1 < "$IN") <(u 2 < "$IN") <(u 3 < "$IN") <(u 4 < "$IN")
```

There are of course many variations, but perhaps the above will be enough for you either to solve the problem yourself or to formulate a more precise question.